# Show that $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ is not Jordan measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to show two things:
1. $J^*([0,1])=1$, where $J^*$ is the Jordan outer measure.
2. $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ is not Jordan measurable - i.e. the Jordan outer and inner measures do not agree.
The Jordan measures here are defined on finite union of open intervals.

Any hints or proof help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: there are no intervals that contain only rational numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow.

Comment: Compute upper and lower sums for the function $=1$ on the rationals, $=0$ on the irrationals.

Comment: What is the measure of a singleton? Say $J ( \{ q\ } )$, where $q  \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @GEdgar What do you mean lower and upper sums? Measure of a singleton is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$1). \underline c(\mathbb Q\cap I)=0$ because $\mathbb Q\cap I$ has empty interior.

$2).$ To see that $\overline c(\mathbb Q\cap I)=1$, note that for any $\epsilon>,\ m([0,1+\epsilon)=1+\epsilon$, and that any finite sequence of intervals that covers $\mathbb Q\cap I$ must in fact cover all of $I$.

A useful fact which has been alluded to in the comments, is that $E$ is Jordan measurable if and only if the Riemann integral $\int \chi_E$ exists.

Comment: $I= [0,1]$ and yes it has outer measure $1$

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail please? I'm having a hard time following every step. :/

Comment: $1).$ is just the definition of the inner measure. There are two parts to $2).$ The first will show that the outer measure is $\le 1$, and the second will show that the outer measure cannot be strictly less than $1$.

Comment: 1). How do I show that $\mathbb Q\cap I$ has an empty interior? 2). Why should the finite sequence cover all of $I$?

Comment: It has empty interior because it contains no interval. To understand the second part, [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/509S07/jordan-meas.pdf) is a basic explanation of Jordan measure than should help you with the definitions. It's in $\mathbb R^2$ but the definitions are mutatis mutandis, the same in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for that. How can I show $J^*([0,1])=1$ though?